# Кнопка "обзор" (файлов) в python через tkinter

Tags: python

В загрузчиках виндовса есть кнопка "обзор" которая помогает выбрать путь к файлу или директории. Меня интересует именно путь к файлу. Надо вывести это в отдельную функцию (показ окна проводника). Искал везде, не нашел. Заренее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй tkinter, к примеру.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

file= filedialog.askopenfilename()

if file != "":
    file = str(file)
else:
    print("Не выбран файл")
```